# Why doesn't this code return the number value?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to retrieve a value from a number text box and cannot get the value entered.

```js
var doc_repo = "TEST"
alert(doc_repo)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="sqlentry" name="repository">
```

This will return TEST

I enter a number in the field but when I click the button to get the value I get nothing.

```js
var doc_repo = document.getElementById("sqlEntry").value;
alert(doc_repo)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="sqlentry" name="repository">
```

I am expecting to get a number displayed but I get nothing.

Comment: Because `"sqlentry" !== "sqlEntry"`.

Comment: Error in the console is a hint `message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null",`

Comment: you need to add event listeners. and listen to the change and then alert it. And also sqlentry typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pay attention to large and lower case

```js
var doc_repo = document.getElementById("sqlentry").value;
alert(doc_repo)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am working now.

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes you went into :

- it's `sqlentry` not `sqlEntry` as the `getElementById` method's selector is case-sensitive.
- "*I enter a number in the field but when I click the button to get the value I get nothing*" I don't see any `button` in your code and you'll need a click event listener (attached to the `button`) if you want to get the value after a button click.

Here's a demo :

```js
/**
* @const doc_repo the input element.
* @const btn the button on which you click to get the input's value.
**/
const doc_repo = document.getElementById("sqlentry"),
  btn = document.getElementById("btn");

/** attach click event listener to the button **/
btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(doc_repo.value)); /** log the value **/

/** you could use "alert" method instead of "console.log", I didn't use it to maintain a better user experience on this SO page **/
```

```html
<input type="number" id="sqlentry" name="repository" />
<button id="btn">get value</button>
```

This does the trick but you'll get an empty result if the `input` is empty ! To bypass that we can check if the `input` has a value otherwise we print `0`.

```js
const doc_repo = document.getElementById("sqlentry"),
  btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(doc_repo.value || 0));
/** 
 * the "||" operator returns the left operand if it's true otherwise it returns the right operand
 * as empty string is falsy the "||" operator returns 0 when the input is empty. 
 **/
```

```html
<input type="number" id="sqlentry" name="repository" />
<button id="btn">get value</button>
```